# Android - Back stack is not maintained when app is moved to background and bring to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having 3 activities in my app and the flow is like A->B->C. When I was in activity C, I moved the app to background by pressing the home button. I brought the app to foreground again and it showed activity C as expected. When I press back key, it's closing the app and B and A are not shown.

I put the launch mode for A, C as single instance and for B, nothing is specified. I want to have one instance for all my activities. I have tried by changing the launch mode to single task(with permutation and combinations of all activities) and it didn't work.

Here is my manifest looks like for activity declaration

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_myway_circular_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name="A"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="B"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name="C"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
</application>
```

Can someone tell me how to maintain the back stack always even when the app is opened from background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some manifest declarations

Comment: @snachmsm Thanks for the reply. I have updated my query with the manifest details.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the question gets removed from the list of open questions and that may also help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found that it's the problem with the launch mode. As per Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode), for this mode, the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task

But I wonder the issue is only coming when the app brought to foreground from background. If it is continuously running on foreground, issue is not there.

Finally, I changed it to default mode and it's working now.

Comment: You do not need any special launch modes. The default behaviour should do exactly what you want. Special launch modes cause more problems than they solve, especially if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @DavidWasser I want to have only one instance for all activities in my app at any point of time. That's why I used singleInstance mode.

Comment: That is the default behaviour from Android unless your app is started by another app, in which case you need to determine where you want your app's activities to run, in the foreign app's task or in your own task. But generally speaking you do not need to use special launch  modes to get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the parent(previous Activity) of any activity in the Manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_myway_circular_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name="A"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="B"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".A"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="C"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".B"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and its not working.